# Capybara testing value of hidden field

Tags: capybara

I have a form with a hidden field that contains the current date.

I'm trying to figure out how to write a capybara finder to:

1. Check that the field is there
2. Check the value of the field

Is this possible with Capybara?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its simple you can do it by using `find_by_css` or by using xpath as follow

```
page.find_by_css('#foo .bar a') #foo is the id the foo has .bar class
page.find('/table/tbody/tr[3]') #path of the element we want to find
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up with the following `elem = page.find_by_id( 'my_element_id' ) ; elem.value.should eq Date.today.to_s`

Comment: I also used [`find_by_id`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders:find_by_id): `assert_equal photo.updated_at.to_datetime.to_s, page.find_by_id('hidden_field_photo_updated_at').value.to_datetime.to_s`

Answer (score 51):

just do this:

```
find("#id_of_hidden_input", :visible => false).value
```

Comment: This is just to find the element, this post talks about how to test against it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066884/how-to-get-the-hidden-element-value-in-capybara

Comment: I think this should be `visible: :hidden`, it discusses the options hash in the `all` method, but it applies to find as well. http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Finders#all-instance_method

Answer (score 10):

the matcher `has_field?` works with hidden fields as well. no need to do weird gymnastics with `find` or `all` in this context.

```
page.has_field? "label of the field", type: :hidden, with: "field value"
page.has_field? "id_of_the_field", type: :hidden, with: "field value"
```

the key here is setting the `:type` option to `:hidden` explicitly.

*why use a label with a hidden field?* this comes in handy if you're using a js library, like flatpickr, that cloaks your original text field to hide it. not coupling your behavior tests to specific markup is always a good thing.

Answer (score 6):

You could also instruct Capybara to not ignore hidden elements globally in your `spec_helper.rb` or equivalent. The default behaviour can be overridden:

```
# default behavior for hidden elements
# Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false

# find all elements (hidden or visible)
page.all(".articles .article[id='foo']")

# find visible elements only (overwrite the standard behavior just for this query)
page.all(".articles .article[id='foo']", :visible => true)


# changing the default behavior (e.g. in your features/support/env.rb file)
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = true

# now the query just finds visible nodes by default
page.all(".articles .article[id='foo']")

# but you can change the default behaviour by passing the :visible option again
page.all(".articles .article[id='foo']", :visible => false)
```

Examples taken from [this article](http://makandracards.com/makandra/7617-change-how-capybara-sees-or-ignores-hidden-elements).