# How to get the hidden element value in capybara?

Tags: ruby, capybara

I need to get the value of a hidden element.

I tried the following code:

```
page.find(:xpath, "//span[@id='sample']").text
```

it returns nil.

Comment: Please show the html of the page.

Comment: @JustinKo Acutally knowing whole HTML isn't necessary

Comment: @AndreyBotalov, I just wanted to confirm if we are looking at a span that is not visible or an input element of type 'hidden'. There have been confusions over this before in other questions.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From Capybara 2.1 you can pass `:all` to `text` and use `find('#sample').text(:all)` regardless of driver.

Also you can use `:text` option of matchers (they will internally pass `:all` to `text` if `:visible` is `false`):

```rb
page.should have_css('#sample', visible: false, text: 'expected text')
```

---

In older Capybara 2.0.x `text` didn't have such option and returned only visible text.

To return both visible and not visible text you can use in:

- selenium:

```rb
page.evaluate_script("document.getElementById('sample').textContent")
```

- rack_test:

```rb
find('#sample').native.text
```

Comment: @Dean I think it should work. I've just assumed that OP wants to get text, not value.

Answer (score 27):

You can simply find the hidden element and get it's value.

```
find('#sample', visible: false).value
```

So simple ;)